# Phpmailer I am not getting any attachment, but i am receiving mail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

This is form for applying visa. 
Everything in code is working fine. files are uploaded also getting mail for both user and admin. But for admin mail files are not attached in mail.

Below is my php code.
(Code is not in an optimized manner just a beginner)

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if (isset ($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit']!='')) {
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $first_name = $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
     // file upload for passport document
    if (isset($_FILES["passport"]["name"]) && $_FILES["passport"]["name"] !='') {
        $file_name     = $_FILES["passport"]["name"];
        $target_dir    = "documents/";
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $target_file   = $target_dir .$first_name.'passport'. time().'.'.$imageFileType;
        $passportnme   = $first_name.'passport'.time().'.'.$imageFileType;

        if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            &&  $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "doc") {
            $passporterror = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF & Docx files are allowed.";
        } else if ($_FILES["passport"]["size"] > 500000) {
            $passporterror = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["passport"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                $success       = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["passport"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                $passporterror = "";
            } else {
                $passporterror = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $passporterror = "Please choose file";
    }
     // file upload for photo document
    if (isset($_FILES["photo"]["name"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["name"] !='') {
        $file_name2     = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
        $target_dir2    = "documents/";
        $imageFileType2 = pathinfo($file_name2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $target_file2   = $target_dir2 .$first_name.'photo'. time().'.'.$imageFileType2;
        $photonme       = $first_name.'photo'.time().'.'.$imageFileType2;

        if ($imageFileType2 != "jpg" && $imageFileType2 != "png" && $imageFileType2 != "jpeg"
            &&  $imageFileType2 != "pdf" && $imageFileType2 != "docx" && $imageFileType2 != "doc") {
            $photoerror = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF & Docx files are allowed.";
        } else if ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > 500000) {
            $photoerror = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2)) {
                $success2 = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["photo"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                $photoerror = "";
            } else {
                $photoerror = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $photoerror = "Please choose file";
    }
     // file upload for Ticket document
    if (isset($_FILES["tickets"]["name"]) && $_FILES["tickets"]["name"] !='') {
        $file_name3     = $_FILES["tickets"]["name"];
        $target_dir3    = "documents/";
        $imageFileType3 = pathinfo($file_name3,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $target_file3   = $target_dir3.$first_name.'tickets'. time().'.'.$imageFileType3;
        $ticketsnme     = $first_name.'tickets'.time().'.'.$imageFileType3;

        if ($imageFileType3 != "jpg" && $imageFileType3 != "png" && $imageFileType3 != "jpeg"
            &&  $imageFileType3 != "pdf" && $imageFileType3 != "docx" && $imageFileType3 != "doc") {
            $ticketserror = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF & Docx files are allowed.";
        } else if ($_FILES["tickets"]["size"] > 500000) {
            $ticketserror = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tickets"]["tmp_name"], $target_file3)) {
                $success3     = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["tickets"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                $ticketserror = "";
            } else {
                $ticketserror = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $ticketserror = "Please choose file";
    }
     // php mailer begins here for sending email for user
    //Load composer's autoloader
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions

    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP         
        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->Host = 'smtpout.asia.secureserver.net';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'xxxx@xxxx.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';                           // SMTP password
        //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = xxxx;                                    // TCP port to connect to
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('support@visamalaysiaonline.com', 'Visa Malaysia Online');
        $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
        $mail->addReplyTo('support@visamalaysiaonline.com', 'Visa Malaysia Online');

        //Content$ticketsnme
        $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Malaysian Visa Online';
        $mail->Body = 'Hi '.$name.'<br> Thank you . We wil Reply or get back to you within 24hrs</h3>';
        $mail->send();
        echo "<h3>Thank you . We wil Reply or get back to you within 24hrs</h3>";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<h4>Error try again later</h4>";
    }
     // php mailer begins here for sending email for Admin
    $mail2 = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail2->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail2->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP        
        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail2->Host = 'smtpout.asia.secureserver.net';
        $mail2->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail2->Username = 'xxxx@xxxxx.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail2->Password = 'xxxxx';                           // SMTP password
        //$mail2->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail2->Port = xxxx;                                    // TCP port to connect to
        //Recipients
        $mail2->setFrom('support@visamalaysiaonline.com', 'Visa Malaysia Online');
        $mail2->addAddress('support@visamalaysiaonline.com', 'Visa Malaysia Online');
        $mail2->addReplyTo('support@visamalaysiaonline.com', 'Visa Malaysia Online');
        $mail->addAttachment("documents/$passportnme");         // Add attachments
        $mail->addAttachment("documents/$photonme", "documents/$ticketsnme");    // Optional name
        //Content
        $mail2->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
        $mail2->Subject = 'Application for Visa Request';
        $mail2->Body = '<html><body><table rules="all" style="border-color: rgb(130,0,67);" cellpadding="10"><tr><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>'.$phone.'</td></tr></table></body></html>';
        $mail2->send();
        echo "<h3>admin mailsent</h3>";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<h4>admin mail falied</h4>";
    }
}
?> <?php 
echo $success.'<br>';
echo $passporterror.'<br>';
echo $success2.'<br>';
echo $photoerror.'<br>';
echo $success3.'<br>';
echo $ticketserror.'<br>';
echo $passportnme.'<br>';
echo $photonme.'<br>';
echo $ticketsnme.'<br>';
?>
```

This is my html code

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="#" method="post" class="contact-form" id="get-in-touch" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <ul>
                    <li><label for="">Name: </label><input name="name" class="form-control input-box" value="" type="text" required> </li>
                    <li><label for="">Email: </label><input name="email" class="form-control input-box" value="" type="email" required> </li>
                    <li><label for="">Phone: </label><input name="phone" class="form-control input-box" value="" type="text" required> </li>
                    <li><label for="">Scanned colour copy of the first and the last page of your passport :</label>
                        <input name="passport" class="form-control input-box"  type="file" required></li>
                    <li><label for="">Scanned colour Passport-size Photographs taken against a white background :</label>
                        <input name="photo" class="form-control input-box"  type="file" required></li>
                    <li><label for="">Confirmed air tickets (onward & return) :</label>
                        <input name="tickets" class="form-control input-box"  type="file" required></li>
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit">

            </form>
```

I don't know what is error in this code iam not getting any attachments to my admin mail

Out put i got

[image]

Comment: add `echo $passportnme; die;`  after `try {` and post the output

Comment: I added this code after try {`<?php 
echo $success.'<br>';
echo $passporterror.'<br>';
echo $success2.'<br>';
echo $photoerror.'<br>';
echo $success3.'<br>';
echo $ticketserror.'<br>';
echo $passportnme.'<br>';
echo $photonme.'<br>';
echo $ticketsnme.'<br>';
?>`   I got this out put     `The file 123coimbatore-iso.jpg has been uploaded.

The file desktop-3d-wallpaper-full-hd.jpg has been uploaded.

The file dextop.jpg has been uploaded.

ManojPraharshaTSpassport1519278455.jpg
ManojPraharshaTSphoto1519278455.jpg
ManojPraharshaTStickets1519278455.jpg`

Comment: "This is form for applying visa. " i hope this is not real

Comment: this the link of the form  can check output here http://visamalaysiaonline.com/mail2.php

Comment: 'This is form for applying visa' still lot of things are there but first i need get work with mail first

Comment: 1. Add SMTPDebug = 4 on the second mail (that includes the attachments) and see if you get any info. 2. Try and add an absolute path to the attachments instead.

Answer (score 1):

there was an error in this part
I changed from

```
$mail->addAttachment("documents/$passportnme");         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment("documents/$photonme", "documents/$ticketsnme");    // Optional name
```

To this

```
$mail2->addAttachment("documents/$passportnme");         // Add attachments
    $mail2->addAttachment("documents/$photonme", "documents/$ticketsnme");    // Optional name
```

$mail-> for user 
$mail2-> for admin 
Just a spelling mistake